# Adding buttons to linearlayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I'm trying to add buttons to a linearLayout:

```
public void populateAlarmLayout() {
        Log.d("Array", alarmButtons.size() + "");
        alarmLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alarmlayout);
        for(int i = 0; i < alarmButtons.size(); i++) {
            selectedButton = new Button(this);
            selectedButton.setId(i+1);
            selectedButton.setWidth(150);
            selectedButton.setHeight(150);
            selectedButton.setTextSize(10);
            selectedButton.setText(alarmButtons.get(i));
            selectedButton.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
            selectedButton.setOnLongClickListener(new LongClickListener());
            alarmLayout.addView(selectedButton);
        }
    }
```

I keep getting a `nullpointer` exception at the last line `alarmLayout.addView(selectedButton)` The `alarmlayout` is specified in `alarm.xml` however my current `contentView` is set at `main_activity.xml`. I'm pretty sure this is where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it!

I'm using a `PagerAdapter` so that could be the problem too. Here's the code for that:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.main;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.music;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.alarm;
                break;
            }

            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: findViewById() can only return Views that are in the layout currently displayed, ie main_activity.xml. Otherwise findViewById() will return null, which is what you are seeing. What are you trying to do, add a button to a future layout?

Comment: With `((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);` you are adding your inflated views to index 0 regardless of the `position` parameter. Is that intentional?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I found a template and am trying to figure it all out still

Comment: Try changing it to `((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, position);`

Answer (score 0):

If the alarmlayout isn't in the current view, I believe you need to inflate it before you can add any views to it.

`alarmLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.alarmlayout);`

Comment: isn't that done here:

' View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);'

Comment: It's hard for me to fully understand the structure/flow of your code.  I'm talking about in the function `public void populateAlarmLayout()`.

`alarmLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alarmlayout);` will return null if R.id.alarmlayout is not in your current view.  Therefore, calling `alarmLayout.addView(selectedButton);` will give you a null pointer exception.

Comment: how do I know if my alarmlayout is in the current view? I'm assuming it's not because of the null pointer and in my onCreate() I specifically say setContentView(R.id.main_activity) (which doesn't contain anything, because I thought my ViewPager was supposed to take care of that)

Comment: Note that findViewById is a method which exists in Views and Activities. As the name suggests, it tries to find a view from within another view or an Activity. Since you are calling it from within an activity, the only way to get a reference to the View is by having it inside of the View/Activity from which you are calling the method. And that's independent from the code inside the viewpager. What do you exactly need to do with the alarm layout and the buttons? You can add the buttons after inflation from the viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. And as far as I can see the NullPointerException may come from alarmLayout.
Can you debug your app and put a pair of interruption points to confirm that?

Based on this, could you check that the name of the resource is exactly how it looks in your xml?:

```
alarmLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alarmlayout);
```

Comment: Yup, the error is in alarmLayout. I checked my xml:
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/alarmlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

Everything matches up...

Comment: Make sure you set the view (setContentView(R.layout.view)) to the activity prior to calling "populateAlarmLayout" and double check as well that alarmlayout is inside of that view.

Comment: right now i'm in R.layout.activity_main, but alarmlayout is in R.layout.alarm. The LayoutInflater should be taking care of that thou...but it's not (i don't think)

If i change the view to R.layout.alarm, it works fine.
I'm using a PagerAdapter, so I can slide between views by swiping left/right. If, when i swipe to alarm, i set my view to R.layout.alarm, I can swipe back to the other layouts, it's stuck on that view.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem I think. I had a GUI but couldn't access it in my java file. I also tried to do it by initializing a new LinearLayout.

But than i tried it with ViewGroup and the id I set before, for my LinearLayout.

My code looks like this:

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llActOver);
Button btTest = new Button(this);
btTest.setText("Test Button");
linearLayout.addView(btTest);
```